# passing a string-array and the foreach loop do not work: no array but one string?

Tags: arrays, function, powershell

I have an array of ntp-server passed at a function to loop through that. This is what happens:

```
  $srvA = @(
      '0.at.pool.ntp.org',
      '1.at.pool.ntp.org',
      '2.at.pool.ntp.org',
      '3.at.pool.ntp.org'
  )

  Function Get-NtpTime {
      param($srvList)
      $srvList
      $nSrv = $srvList.Length
      foreach ( $Server in $srvList ) {
          $nSrv--
          Write-Host $Server $nSrv
      }
  }

  Get-NtpTime $srvA
  0.at.pool.ntp.org 1.at.pool.ntp.org 2.at.pool.ntp.org 3.at.pool.ntp.org
  0.at.pool.ntp.org 1.at.pool.ntp.org 2.at.pool.ntp.org 3.at.pool.ntp.org 70
```

As you see $srvList seems to be one sring not an array of strings and
$Server is not a single server but all and the length is 70 not 4.
The definition of the array seems to be incorrect but where why and how?
(I tried version of 1 line-array - no difference)

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running? Running the exact code you show on v4 I get the expected results, not what you got.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I don't know the version, but this is very basic?

Comment: I got the solution - I just had to restart the ISE - funny.

Answer (score 2):

You should type your `$srvList` parameter as an array.

```
function Get-NtpTime
{
    param(
        [string[]]
        $srvList
    )

    # ...snip...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630616/passing-a-string-array-and-the-foreach-loop-do-not-work-no-array-but-one-string#comment-40045267) that restarting the ISE fixed the issue, it sounds like `$srvA` had been declared as a string variable at one point during the session. Once declared with a specific type, PowerShell will coerce any future assignments to the variable's declared type:

```
> $a = @( 'one', 'two', 'three' )  # No type declaration
> $a
one
two
three

> [string]$b = @( 'one', 'two', 'three' )  # Declared as string
> $b
one two three

> $b = @( 'four', 'five' )  # Re-using variable declared as string
> $b
four five
```

You could fix this in the current session by re-declaring the variable as the desired type, in this case using `[string[]]$srvA = @( ... )`.